# I seek a SF short story where the husband created a time machine which could only go back to one place & time but the wife was delighted

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I seek a SF short story where the husband created a time machine which could only go back to one place & time but the wife was delighted, for she could go back to a real butcher shop with incredibly economical prices.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Though it's not what you have in mind, I must say this description of the story reminds me of the song "Everything You Know is Wrong" by Weird Al Yankovic: "They offered to transport me back to any point in history that I would care to go, and so I had them send me back to last Thursday night so I could pay my phone bill on time..."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is ["The Good Provider"](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56059) by Marion Gross.  This [review](https://sfmagazines.com/?p=3148) discusses the feature you mentioned:

> The Good Provider by Marion Gross is an overly contrived tale about an
> inventor who creates a time machine—but it will only take him to a
> specific place in the nearby town, only twenty years ago, and only for
> twenty minutes. **His wife uses it to get cheap meat from the butcher**. I
> realise that not all SF can have an epic scope, but . . .

It's collected in [50 Short Science Fiction Tales](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?403556), which is where I read it.

Comment: Wait, so she can only get cheap meat *once*, presumably?

Comment: @Adamant I think the time machine can be used multiple times, just the place and time is always the same.

Comment: 20 minutes is enough time to send myself a letter with winning lottery numbers.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong but if it sent you to the same time, then you would meet yourself that you've sent previously? Or I guess this uses alternate worldline philosophy then

Comment: I've read the story.  It always sends you to the same place.  The time is always "twenty years ago." (Something like that.)  If you make a trip to the past starting on consecutive days, then the butcher in the past will see you coming in to the shop on consecutive days.

Comment: I could remember the story, but no particulars. The comments have stirred the mud of memory. The lady used the machine regularly for her shopping. I recall the butcher being very respectable to a customer with apparently lots of money to spend. (and, considering the time the book was written/set, there was no casual lottery to buy into)

Comment: @Edheldil: The machine takes you to the past, so sending yourself a letter doesn't help.  You already know the winning lottery numbers from 20 years ago, so you could buy a ticket when you go back, but you wouldn't have time to collect your winnings.

Comment: @NateEldredge: but you could go back a week later, couldn't you?

Comment: @Blaze There are lots of other types of betting or other money making opportunities which could be easily used, rather than a lottery. For example, sports betting, horse racing, the stock market, business opportunities, etc. Being able to send effectively unlimited information to yourself in the past could be taken advantage of in a plethora of ways.

Comment: @NateEldredge What was proposed was just sending your past self information from the future. That could be taken advantage of by your past self in many ways. Most, however, would change your personal timeline, which might prevent developing the time machine. So, depending on how time functions in the story's universe, great care might be needed to prevent affecting your past self. At a minimum, the story demonstrates that you can make changes that are sufficiently minor such that they don't affect you.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the public domain by now? I'm surprised that I can't find a copy online.

Comment: @Mayken With the general idea of time travel, you're 100% correct. In this short story, though, the machine is strictly limited. As mentioned by others, I recall it being sent to the same spot (a modest commercial street in a residential area) 20 years ago and being able to stay for only 20 minutes. Throw in the tactical mix that the hero is a woman of very limited means, which is why being able to buy groceries at the prices of yesterday is pure bliss for her. She would need to do some truly fancy stepping to engage your list of options under those conditions.